# ShinyUI - How to add vertical / horizontal lines in a fluidrow/col grid?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I have 8 tables on a screen and would like to split them in four panes. **How can I add vertical and horizontal lines into my `fluidrow()` + `column()` grid please?**

**Target design:**

[image]

**Current design:**

[image]

**Reproducible code:**

```
DTWrapper <- function(data){
  datatable(data, 
            options = list(dom='t',ordering=F, 
                           columnDefs=list(list(targets=1:2, className="dt-right"))), 
            caption= htmltools::tags$caption(
              style = "caption-side: left; text-align: left; color:black;", "Title"), 
            rownames = FALSE)
}
################################################################################
server = function(input, output) {

  ds <- head(mtcars[,1:3])
  output$one <- DT::renderDataTable(DTWrapper(ds))
  output$two <- DT::renderDataTable(DTWrapper(ds))
  output$three <- DT::renderDataTable(DTWrapper(ds))
  output$four <- DT::renderDataTable(DTWrapper(ds))
  output$five <- DT::renderDataTable(DTWrapper(ds))
  output$six <- DT::renderDataTable(DTWrapper(ds))
  output$seven <- DT::renderDataTable(DTWrapper(ds))
  output$eight <- DT::renderDataTable(DTWrapper(ds))
}
################################################################################
ui = fluidPage(

  fluidRow(column(2, DT::dataTableOutput("one"),style='margin-bottom:30px; padding: 5px;') 
           ,column(2,
                   DT::dataTableOutput("two"),style='margin-bottom:30px;border-right:1px solid; padding: 5px;')  
           ,column(2,
                   DT::dataTableOutput("three"),style='margin-bottom:30px; padding: 5px;')  
           ,column(2,
                   DT::dataTableOutput("four"),style='margin-bottom:30px; padding: 5px;')  
  ), hr(),
  fluidRow(column(2,
                  DT::dataTableOutput("five"),style='margin-bottom:30px; padding: 5px;') 
           ,column(2,style='margin-bottom:30px;border-right:1px solid; padding: 5px;') 
           ,column(2,
                   DT::dataTableOutput("seven"),style='margin-bottom:30px; padding: 5px;') 
           ,column(2,
                   DT::dataTableOutput("eight"),style='margin-bottom:30px; padding: 5px;') 
  )
)
shinyApp(server=server, ui=ui)
```

**Edit:**

Following @Hao's answer, I tried adding `border-right` styling to the `column(.)`, but the result is not yet as hoped.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49098544/914686

Answer (score 1):

You can put `border: 1px solid` in the style section of your column.

```
column(2, DT::dataTableOutput("one"),
  style='margin-bottom:30px;border:1px solid; padding: 10px;')
```

Or you can define a css class in a `tags$head` in UI and just call the class name here.

---

Seems like you want some panels?

I would use something like

```
tags$div(
class = "panel panel-default", 
tags$div(class="panel-heading", "xxxx"),
tags$div(
class="panel-body",
row(column(...), column(...))
)
```

Comment: Thx. I have tried to add the some borders to the table individually, but it dos not completely solve the issue yet. I edited my question accordingly :).