# Shiny - Draw Right Border Of Column

Tags: html, r, shiny

Suppose I have the following Shiny ui code:

```
fluidRow(
  column(
    width=4
  ),

  column(
    width=8
  )
)
```

How can I draw the right border of the first column?

Comment: Add custom css? Shiny doesn't support drawing lines on the column borders i guess.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add CSS to the column using the `style` argument. So one way to do this would be:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(style='border-right: 1px solid red',
      width=4,
      p('Hello')
    ),

    column(
      width=8,
      p('World')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input,output) {}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes @Florian many thanks! I did know about the custom CSS option but could not get it to draw the line. I missed the 'solid' you put in there. That is what happens when you try to customize Shiny without knowing CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach this is to create the html style outside of the object (the column in this case) and assign the column a css class.  By creating the style in this way, you can apply the style to another column more efficiently.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
tags$head(
tags$style(HTML("
  
  .column_w_bar {
      border-right-color: #eb4034;
      border-right-width: 1px;
      border-right-style: solid;
}
") # end HTML
) # end tags$style
) # end tags$head

fluidRow(
  column(class = 'column_w_bar',
      width=4
  ),

  column(
      width=8
  )
 ) # end fluidRow
) # end FluidPage
```

In this example, it is within the R code using `tags$head()` and `tags$style()`.
You can also create the styles in a separate .css file within the 'www' folder in a shiny project.